# Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid) is so slow at startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

My laptop is Dell Inspiron N4050 that its RAM was upgraded to 8 GB. I have dual boot OS (Win8 and Ubuntu). My laptop is so slow when booting from Ubuntu *It takes about 2 minutes* but Win8 will boot at max 30 seconds.

- I tried to use bootchart but I dont have any .png file in /var/log/bootchart.
- I looked for bootchart from wiki.ubuntu  "[here is link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting)" . It says me the following line
- To generate a chart, edit the "linux" line in the grub boot menu and append init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart.
- Here is my grub boot menu entery :

  ```
  recordfail
  load_video
  gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
  insmod gzio
  if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='hd0,msdos1'
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245
  fi
  linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic root=UUID=a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
  initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-18-generic
  ```
- I changed linux  "/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic root=UUID=a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff" with "init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart". But it did NOT boot with this entery. Kernel errors.
- I really do NOT understand what I need to change exactly. (About "linux" line)
- Someone said me that you must look for your dmesg output for the timeout but I dont understand what they are.
- [Here is my dmesg output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQUGNCSnA2UXlNemM/view?usp=sharing) here is my small output for dmesg :

  ```
  [    7.016302] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
  [    7.078613] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <makgun02>.
  [   10.002143] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
  [   10.002154] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
  [   11.681306] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
  [   16.816490] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047f (\PMIO) (20141107/utaddress-258)
  [   16.816498] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
  [   16.816503] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GPIO) (20141107/utaddress-258)
  ```

Comment: What the Ubuntu wiki is suggesting is that, in your grub menu, the line beginning with *linux* should be: `linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic root=UUID=a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff  init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart`. Please make this modification, then come back with your bootchart output. It is true your dmesg ouput displays an amazing slowness.   Once turned on, is your pc slow at all, or just normal?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I tried this and it crates bootchart-**.svg and it boots at 2 mins like just normally. I looked for the file for any errors but I think I didnt understand what the error is.

Comment: Could you please post  the output, like you did for the dmesg output?

Comment: Sorry I forgot upload it :(  {https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQeUlRVHh4bVBWMUU/view?usp=sharing} HERE is link.

Comment: Please eliminate the expression `$vt_handoff$` from the grub menu entry, reboot, and tell me whether this has made your system any faster.

Comment: I editted like this linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-18-generic root=UUID=a90bae77-92d4-4223-a83d-c96b4dd35245 ro quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd-bootchart. And here is link new svg {https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQUGduQ180dHhlcTQ/view?usp=sharing}

Comment: I also saw this line when I press F12 at boot. 

`A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c3f3694c\x2d6422\x2d4773\x2da839\x2deac8beb0ec66.device (1min 4s/1min 30s)`

Comment: Pls see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I also saw this line when I press F12 at boot:
>
> `A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c3f3694c\x2d6422\x2d4773\x2da839\x2deac8beb0ec66.device (1min 4s/1min 30s)`

**Perfect!!! This is what I was hoping for!!!**

This message implies that one of the partitions referenced in `/etc/fstab` cannot be mounted properly. You should check your `fstab` file and fix the problem. The faulty partition can be anything, including missing `swap`.

If you do not know how to do it, then please post the output of (as `sudo`):

```
       cat /etc/fstab
       blkid
       fdisk -l
```

or, if the last command complains about something, use the command

```
       gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

instead.

It is most likely that the timer you saw at the end of error message above (`1min 4s/1min 30s`) is responsible for your very slow starts.

**EDIT:**

The second of these two lines,

```
  # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=c3f3694c-6422-4773-a839-eac8beb0ec66 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

should be modified as follows:

```
 # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
  UUID=ce9a1c12-733e-4aad-946a-47962a1dd5ab none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Save, reboot, let me know.

Comment: I typed all in one commad line is there : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQczlaMUoxOXlOem8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: With this modification it booted in 1 min and 20 secs it reduces 40 secs for boot time

Comment: Again it booted 1min20secs

Comment: @makgun Can you see any other message if you hit F12 at boot?

Comment: Yes but I cant saw it as text. I can take a video

Comment: `here is the video link :` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQUkY2Zl81TkJTUEk/view?usp=sharing


`here is my text that I wrote it :` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU9v801buWQT192c05ZWnEycUU/view?usp=sharing